# Getting the result of a particular thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, thread-safety

Level: Beginner

I am currently working with pythonv2.7 on windows 7 OS. I have a question regarding threads. I am actually working on an GUI app with wxPython and python. During my project I have a situation where I need to check some value from a server infinitely (Of course pausing for some time interval too). So in my programm I have a method `X(self, code)` that gets the value from the server. This method `X(self, code)` requires an argument called code. Depending upon the value of the argument  `code` the server will return a value. Now I need to call this method `X(self, code)` infinitely with all possible values of the `code` to get all the values from the server so that my values are up to date. So, I thought of implementing threads, so that each thread will use a particular value of the `code` and use  `X(self, code)` method to get the value from the server for that particular value of the `code` and return it. I have a problem in doing so. The threads are being created and returning values but I don't understand *how can I get the results of a particular thread?*  I think that I not implementing a good logic. It would be nice if someone can suggest some thing better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question, and not entering in the correctness of your solution.

The [`Thread` objects have a `name` attribute](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) that identifies the thread. Therefore, you can use:

```
print "%s Whatever" % self.name
```

in your `print` statements (or even better, create a print method that prepends the thread name and use that instead).

Comment: Thanks. Printing the thread name is fine, but can I use this name to get the results of that particular thread too. The docs says more than one thread can have same name.

Comment: It can be the same if you set it: "By default, a unique name is constructed of the form “Thread-N” where N is a small decimal number."